# Is there a way to make an input affect another input in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am tinkering with an indicator which displays different session timings on the screen.

I want to build an option where a single option would turn on/off these session displays simultaneously.

[image: What I want to see happening.]

I did this:

```
if killzone_killswitch == true
   LO, NYO, LC, AO, NYC := false
```

And that does not work.

So, does anyone if this is even doable or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is doable. Here is an example. You can add this to your chart and toggle input 1, when you do notice the others change. However it wont show them as false in the settings, but for code execution they are false. Hence the label I added for visual.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
inp1 = input.bool(false)
inp2 = input.bool(true)
inp3 = input.bool(true)
inp4 = input.bool(true)

if inp1 == true
    inp2 := false
    inp3 := false
    inp4 := false

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(inp1) + '\n' + str.tostring(inp2) + '\n' + str.tostring(inp3) + '\n' + str.tostring(inp4), color = color.aqua)
```